# $\int_A e^{2y} d(x,y)$ with $A := \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: 0 \leq x \leq 3, x \leq y \leq 3\}$

Tags: calculus, integration, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Let the set $A := \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: 0 \leq x \leq 3, x \leq y \leq 3$}

I want to know what's the easiest way to make a sketch of this (by hand)?

Of course, I could just use Wolfram Alpha and get it, but what's the best way to do it step-by-step? What I'm stuck with is the part where we realize that it's not a square.

[image]

Also, if we have this integral: $\int_A e^{2y} d(x,y)$, how can I calculate it with the set above?

Would I have to do the following?

$$\int_0^3 \int_0^ye^{2y} \text{dx dy} = \int_0^3 e^{2y} x = \int_0^3 e^{2y} \cdot 3 \text{ dy} = \frac{3e^{6} - 3}{2}$$

I have doubts that this is true.

Comment: The boundaries of integration area are given by inequalities: $0\leq x$, $x \leq 3$, $x \leq y$ and $y\leq 3$. To plot sketch you need to draw lines $0=x$, $x=3$, $x=y$, $y=3$ and indicate what semi-plane is corresponding to inequality sign. Then you need to find intersection of all semi-planes/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just note that the definition of $A$ explicitly includes the bounds on $x$ and $y$... The integral can be computed as
$$
\int_0^3 \int_x^3 e^{2y} dy\, dx = \int_0^3\frac 12(e^6-e^{2x})dx= \cdots =\frac{1}{4} \left(1+5 e^6\right)
$$

Answer (score 2):

Well, it would have been a square had you been given $0 \le x \le 3, 0 \le y \le 3$. But instead, you have $x \le y \le 3$, so you can use that as the bounds for the integral directly:
$$
\int_A e^{2y}dxdy = \int_{x=0}^{x=3} \int_{y=x}^{y=3} e^{2y} dydx
$$

Notice the inner integral is $dy$ with bounds depending on $x$, and the outer one integrates $dx$ with constant bounds so the result is constant.

---

**EXTRA CREDIT**

Note that the region can also be rewritten to integrate $dx$ first. When you fix some $x$, note the left-hand boundary is at $0$ and the right-hand boundary is at $y$, so you have $0 \le x \le y$ while $0 \le y \le 3$, so you can also integrate
$$
\int_A e^{2y}dxdy
 = \int_{x=0}^{x=3} \int_{y=x}^{y=3} e^{2y} dydx
 = \int_{y=0}^{y=3} \int_{x=0}^{x=y} e^{2y} dx dy.
$$